# Lightbox: can't access parent javascript obj from iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, ckeditor, highslide

I'm using a lightbox (highslide JS / highslide.com) which when opens displays a  WYSIWYG Javascript editor (CKEditor / ckeditor.com). I call the lightbox (or expander) like so:

```
<a href="script.php" onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this,{objectType:'iframe'})">click here</a>
```

In the parent page I include the javascript for the editor:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

The first line (truncated) of ckeditor.js is:

```
(function(){if(window.CKEDITOR&&window.CKEDITOR.dom)return;if(!window.CKEDITOR)window.CKEDITOR=(function()
```

My problem, is that the editor does not work in the expander - **TypeError: parent.window.hs.CKEDITOR is undefined**

To fix this I need to call the ckeditor.js in script.php which makes the expander slow to open as it has to pull the JS file again, even though the parent window has already done so.

CK editor is called thus in iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.replace( 'bodytext' ,
{
basePath : '/admin/ckeditor/'
});
</script>
```

I have tried prefixing CKEDITOR with `'parent' , 'parent.window', 'window'` all without success

If there any fix for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I correctly understood your question, but based on:

> In the parent page I include the javascript for the editor:

My answer is - you have to include `ckeditor.js` in the same document in which you use it.

Comment: Hi, I have it working that way, calling the JS again in my lightbox. The JS file is over 300kb so I wanted to just load it in the parent page and thus spped up the opening of the lightbox. Is this not possible?

Comment: The file will be cached by the browser once you load it for the first time.

Comment: That's what I thought should happen but Firebug is showing it pulls it all down each time i open the lightbox with a 200 result. Actually, I've just thought of something, will be in office later and report back:)

Comment: When Firebug is open it may disable caching. Try the same with Chrome dev tools but make sure to disable the "disable caching when dev tools opened" option. Actually - this may be more complex, because your sever's settings may affect the result too. In any case, if everything is configured correctly the files should be cached.

Comment: Hi while writing my last comment I did think to check the server config, and YES I had disabled the cache in an .htaccess for some JSON in a directory above, and had forgot it propagated to my lightbox. Firebug was enough to see it from home and now in office I can confirm it. I'll just move my JSON to another dir and put a local .htaccess there. Thanks!